# $_POST array is sometimes empty

Tags: php, arrays

When submitting my form, sometimes the `$_POST` array is empty and other times it's not (when inputting the exact same thing on the exact same input). 
My `post_max_size` is large `500M` and I'm only inputting values from checkboxes. What could be causing this? I might have thought it was because of a `for` loop I'm using, but the `$_POST` array is fine half the time and empty the other.

```
 <form action="send.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Facebook" value="Facebook" id="Facebook"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Twitter" value="Twitter" id="Twitter"/>
    <?php
    for($i = 0; $i < $blogcount; $i = $i + 1){
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="Tumblr[]" value="'.$bloglist[$i].'" id="Tumblr'.$bloglist[$i].'"/>';
    } 
    ?>
    <input id="myImage" type="file" accept="image/*" name="file" class="upload" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: do you need this `enctype="multipart/form-data"` for normal post??

Comment: you have missed a quote in `echo` at last add one single quote.

Comment: Oh, I do have an image input that I've just removed only for testing purposes (as I thought it might've been enctype making the array empty, but it wasn't), I'll add it into the code

Comment: Sorry, I was typing it out by hand, the last quote was there in the real code...

Comment: See your source code in `html`. How the outputs look like. Is that really what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't check any checkbox, it won't post and thus it would give you empty `$_POST`. All you have to code is `isset($_POST['checkboxname'])`

Comment: All the checkboxes were ticked, and I've been testing with isset(...). Eventually I've just started doing
 var_dump($_POST);die();
but same result...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    for($i = 0; $i < $blogcount; $i = $i + 1){
        ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Tumblr[]" value="<?php echo $bloglist[$i] ?>" id="<?php echo 'Tumblr'.$bloglist[$i] ?>"/>
    <?php
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the same result after a few successful ones. Thanks though!

Comment: @Hook happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have add value to your submit button to work correctly.

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
```

Comment: And how'll that help him